# Repeated measures with sub-sample (and how to select them?)

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design

We conducted an extensive survey on ethical behaviour in the workplace (N=5000). The results give an indication on different scales of the current state of the company. For example, one question is whether people feel respected by their superiors or not.

Now, we are implementing a programme to address some of the scales that came out particularly negative. We'd like to conduct the survey again in, say, 3 months time to see whether there's a change.

Since our N is very large, I thought we wouldn't need to sample every employee again, but instead could invite a sub-sample to complete the survey, and in another 3 months another sub-sample, etc. This to reduce the total time that any one employee spends on the survey (thereby also avoiding survey fatigue).

How statistically valid is this method? In essence it's a simple repeated measures design, but with lots of missing values in the second (and third, etc.) group as compared to the first. Or are there other problems that arise here?

And on a related note (in case the above method is not problematic): is there an ideal way to select the sub-sample, other than just randomly?

Comment: Missing from your question is a clue to what you would consider to be improvement---how much improvement and measured how? // Depending on your answer to that, an overall sample of size 5000 _might_ allow some subsampling. // Roughly relevant: if judging by number of Yes's on Y/N question with % of Yes's aprx 1/2, then 2500 subjects would allow you to get a CI of % Y that is $\pm$ 2%.

Comment: @BruceET, that's a great question. There are 27 questions (statements) currently, each asking for an agreement rating on a 7-point Likert scale. We convert this to % by doing `((x-1)/6)*100` and we use the mean across respondents as the mean value. I was trying to do some power calculations, and to be able to observe a mean increase of 1% (assumed SD=2%), for power=.8 and alpha=.05 we would need a minimum of N=33. Is that what you're getting at?